# UrbanAirShip SDK - Push Notification - classes not resolved

Tags: android, push-notification, push, android-notifications, urbanairship.com

Previously I was using **urbanairship-sdk-7.0.1.aar** in my android application project. Now I've upgraded urbanairship sdk to **urbanairship-sdk:9.0.3**.

After completing this migration, I'm not able to find the below classes which are declared in manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="com.urbanairship.actions.ActionActivity" />

<service android:name="com.urbanairship.richpush.RichPushUpdateService" />

<service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService"/>
```

I've checked the sdk doc for the above classes however, I didn't find any reliable information. Also [urbanairship migration guide](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/documentation/migration/migration-guide-legacy.md) didn't provide much information about these classes.

I think these classes are either removed or deprecated. 
Can anyone help me into this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have added their AAR file as a gradle dependency and the gradle sync is ok, you can search for these files mentioned in the double shift search and see for yourself if the files are missing or deprecated

Comment: @DarshanPania I was using .aar file for old SDK version. now I'm using gradle dependency as below - 

implementation 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:9.0.3'

Comment: Correct, so if the gradle sync is working fine, you can find these files yourself in the Android Studio by pressing `Shift` key twice and putting the file name in the search box. If the file is present it will show up.